# Should I Use "smtp.gmail.com" in Production?

Tags: email, smtp

I'm writing a Django app that needs to send the occasional mail. Definitely not more than 1000 mails a day for now. I was wondering if it is ok to open a new email address in my domain and send my mail through Google's smtp servers at "smtp.gmail.com" even in my production site, or should I just set up and configure a local relay?

Comment: Since hopefully google with reject relay requests you most likely will have to either deliver directly or use a local smtp server as a relay inside your own domain. Only exception: if all messages go to or from a gmail address.

Comment: Google should be able to answer this question regarding their service. What is and is not included in your contract with them is between you and them.

Comment: @EmilVikström I'm not sure whether that was a joke or not. This wasn't a business question, so no idea what contract do I have with them (none in that context). I was merely asking whether their freely available "relayer" is suitable for production servers.

Comment: If you don't have any agreement at all, then no, you should not use other peoples mail servers for relaying e-mail since that is essentially unauthorized usage of computer resources (a crime in many jurisdictions). I stand by my comment: what services a third party is providing can be best answered by that third party (Google in this instance).

Comment: @EmilVikström I think we are still not getting one another. I am not asking whether it is OK to use smtp.gmail.com - that is a given. It is a FREE service Google provides. It has nothing to do with "unauthorized usage of computer resources". The questions was pretty simple - is it "production" quality - meaning stable, reliable etc.

Comment: I agree that I didn't get you. Now you're saying that you *didn't* ask if it is ok to use smtp.google.com, but in your question you *specifically* ask "if it is ok to ... send my mail through Google's smtp servers at 'smtp.gmail.com'".

Comment: @EmilVikström You are missing the context - PRODUCTION environment. Some stuff that are ok when developing are not ok in production. An example is logging. Or weak passwords. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

I chose to install postfix. I want to highlight arkascha's comment that using smtp.gmail.com will only allow you to relay emails to gmail accounts which won't work for me.

I guess the answer is a resounding "NO".